# Unknown flag --from-file (Kubectl)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to create a config map from my mongodb configuration file. I have used the following command:

```
kubectl create configMap mongodb-config-file --from-file=conf=mongodb.cfg
```

and I get this error:

> Error: unknown flag: --from-file
> See 'kubectl create --help' for usage.

Why is `--from-file` an unknown flag? Am I missing something? I'm using windows if that information is useful. I'm still new to kubernetes and kubectl so any extra information on configMaps is welcome.

I tried to find a solution on Google or other stack overflow questions and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax for a `configMap` object creation is as follows:

```
kubectl create configmap NAME [--from-file=[key=]source]
```

The resource object is `configmap` and not `configMap`:

```
kubectl create configmap mongodb-config-file --from-file=conf=mongodb.cfg
```